# Read .txt file that was modified oustide app in runtime

Tags: java, spring, file

I have a txt file, that is located on classpath directory. This txt is converted into List in program during app starts. At some time I have to make some changes in this file and this changes must be appear in my List in the program. I try to load new data from file but all time i receive old values when I receive a message from Listener what file was modified. Is it impossible to read modified data from that file in runtime? I can't find any solution

I tried Files.readAllLines and resourceLoader.getResource but both of them have the same problem

```
@Log4j2
@Service
public class AicService implements FileChangeListener {
    @Value("${.delay}")
    private Duration delay;
    @Value("${filePath}")
    private Resource filePath;
    private List<ClientValue> clients;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        readFile();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(Set<ChangedFiles> changeSet) {
        for(ChangedFiles cfiles : changeSet) {
            for(ChangedFile cfile: cfiles.getFiles()) {
                if(!isLocked(cfile.getFile().toPath())) {
                    try {
                        readFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error(e);
                    }
                    log.debug("Operation: '{}' on file: '{}' is done", cfile.getType(),                 cfile.getFile().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isLocked(Path path) {
        try (FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE); FileLock lock =  ch.tryLock()) {
            return lock == null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void readFile() throws IOException {
        try {
            List<ClientValue> clients = new ArrayList<>();
            Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath.getURI())).stream()
                    .skip(1)
                    .map(line -> line.split(";"))
                    .map(this::createClientValue)
                    .forEach(clients::add);

            this.clients = clients;
            log.debug("Client values: {}", this.clients);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("It was not possible to get the list of client values: clients.txt", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    private ClientValue createClientValue(String[] columns) {
        int i = 0;
        return ClientValue.builder()
                .name(columns[i++])
                .surname(columns[i++])
                .adddress(columns[i])
                .build();
    }`
```

Comment: Don't. If the file is a resource on the classpath, it should be unchanging (and treated as such). If the file is supposed to be changed, it shouldn't be on the classpath. You might get away with it with some ugly hacks, but fundamentally you're fighting the system. Just place the file *anywhere else* and reload it as required.

Comment: Use the resource on the class path as Initial template for a real file, with `Files.copy`.

Comment: What about putting the file in the application's "app data" folder? Here's where IntelliJ stores its files on [macOS, Windows, and Linux](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)